# Como centralizar texto na DIV fazendo com que as linhas se alinhem à esquerda?

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma `<div>` com a propriedade `text-align: center;` para que o texto fique centralizado, porém eu quero que as linhas do textos comecem sempre à esquerda.

Abaixo está um exemplo do que eu quero:

```
             <DIV>               
-----------------------------
|                           |
|      Olá pessoal          |
|      Este é um exemplo.   |
|      Do que eu quero.     |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

Como posso fazer isso? É possível? O código que eu estou utilizando é este:

```css
#myDiv {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Alguns outros elementos... -->
    <div id="info">
        Dado 1: 334<br>Dado 2: 192.2<br>Dado 3: 3455.234
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode simplesmente criar um sub-elemento que seja `display: inline-block;`, o elemento com inline-block não vai ocupar "100%", não especifique medida, apenas deixe que o texto o ajuste, então deverá ficar assim:

```css
#myDiv {
    text-align: center;
}

#info {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Alguns outros elementos... -->
    <div id="info">
        Dado 1: 334<br>Dado 2: 192.2<br>Dado 3: 3455.234
    </div>
</div>
```

Se realmente vai usar outros elementos antes do `#info` você pode usar um simples `<br>` para separar:

```css
#myDiv {
    text-align: center;
}

#info {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Alguns outros elementos... -->
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>baz</p>

    <br>

    <div id="info">
        Dado 1: 334<br>Dado 2: 192.2<br>Dado 3: 3455.234
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou pode criar um "sub-div" dentro de `#info` e aplicar nela o `display: inline-block;` ao invés de aplicar no `#info`

Comment: @LuizFelipe sim, devo ressaltar que usar flex para algo tão trivial assim é como contratar um engenheiro hidráulico para dar descarga no seu vazo por você. Flex e grid são coisas que tem uma série de caracteristicas, inclusive afetam o elemento pai, o que já é outro problema, tem que entender o comportamento do box-model (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/) que é algo que se perdemos pode complicar bastante em uma falha dificil de detectar, acaso ocorra uma falha.

Comment: Devo concordar. :-)